# Golang SQLite: How to prevent file corruption upon unexpected shutdowns?

Tags: sqlite, go-gorm

I'm using github.com/jinzhu/gorm with sqlite on a application that runs on a embedded device. This device may shutdown at any time.

Is there a way to tell sqlite to close/flush everything after every SQL call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQlite [uses transactions](http://www.sqlite.org/transactional.html), and flushes everything when a transaction commits.

So SQLite will be safe by default (unless your device [is broken](http://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html)).

Comment: [`"SQLite is Transactional"`](https://www.sqlite.org/transactional.html) just make sure that the changes either occur completely or not at all, but not preventing database corruption.